# How to resolve the error NameError: name 'SparkConf' is not defined in pycharm

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1 pyspark-shell'
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Stackoverflow')
sc = SparkContext(master="local", appName="test")
sc.setLogLevel("Error")
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag","Transaction").load("C:/Users/Rajaraman/Desktop/task/data/transactions.xml")
```

> Unable to Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Rajaraman/test.py", line 6, in 
> conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Stackoverflow')
> NameError: name 'SparkConf' is not defined

kindly review

Comment: `from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext` import SparkConf before using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import libraries referenced in the code

Add this line to import the referenced package

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
```